# What will happen if you write data to the shared memory that is larger than its size? Try very large data. To what extent can you go?

Tags: linux, operating-system

i want to know what happen when size of date thats write on shared memory larger than the shared memory size

Comment: It depends on what's in your address space at the next location. If it's not assigned to the process, you'll get a segmentation violation.

Comment: Otherwise, you'll overwrite some other part of your memory, and the results are totally unpredictable.

Answer (score 0):

You'll either get a segmentation violation if the memory you try to write to is unassigned or marked write-only, or you'll corrupt some variables in your program and the result is unpredictable (but it will most likely malfunction in some way).